# Simplifying enum definition?

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, enums

I like to use some enums in Swift 3. They are also used as index to an array. So they are Int. I defined them as:

```
enum TypeOfArray: Int {
    case src = 0, dst, srcCache, n
    static var Start: Int { return 0              } 
    static var End  : Int { return n.rawValue - 1 } 

    static let allValues = [src, srcCache, dst]

    init() {
        self = .n
    }
}
```

So using .Start and .End I can use them as loop limits. But whenever I use the names "src" or "dst" itself, I have to add ".rawValue" to get the numeric value to be used as an index.
Is there any way to make it more convenience and to shorten it? (looks very complicated to me for such a simple task)

Comment: Any *simplifying* requires more code. You can either compare the raw value or the enum case, anyway both sides of the comparison must be the same type. You can simplify your code by removing both `get` expressions, they are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I removed get.

Comment: If your array has exactly three elements then you might consider to replace it with a struct or tuple (having `src`, `dst`, `srcCache` properties).